# Cannot load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0' in MSTest project

Tags: c#, nuget, mstest, packagereference, packages.config

I'm having problem with MSTest, Here the issue

- Open VS2019
- Make sure that package management is set to [PackageReference]
- Create a .Net Framework test project
- Add Nuget package Microsoft.Extentions.Configuration last version (3.1.3.0)
- Add the code below
- Run test
- ==> Test fail with error [Cannot load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0 ...] error

PS : using package.config instead of PackageReference solve the issue.
Downgrading to Microsoft.Extentions.Configuration to 3.1.0.0 fixes the issue too

What's the problem here ?

Thanks

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;

namespace TestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().Build();
            Assert.IsNotNull(configuration);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved by enabling [auto binding redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection)

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though I fixed my problem, it's not clear for me why it's requesting version 3.1.0.0 when I added version 3.1.3.0.
I looked at package dependencies, and i didn't find any other package referencing a lower version.
If some one has an idea or a simple thought just drop an answer here.

Thanks.